# Get local network IP programmatically into command prompt

Tags: windows, command-line, console, network-programming

Just as others have asked for other languages, I would like to know how I get the local network IP into the command line (Windows 7) without passing it as a parameter. From this I know it is not saved as an environment variable, although I can see:

```
USERDNSDOMAIN=COMPANY.LOCAL
USERDOMAIN=COMPANY
```

I want to write a script that passes the local network IP address to a Java program and I cannot access the Java program itself.

**EDIT:** No, `ipconfig` won't do because I would have to parse the result. I want a single variable.

Comment: ipconfig will show the information you want

Comment: @Richard I don't want to "see" the information. I want to use it without parsing through a lot of other stuff.

Comment: Unless you set an environment variable from another program, you don't have a choice, you have to do some parsing. It's not that hard.

Answer (score 0):

This will get the IPv4 address of a network adapter. You may have to add more find statements to filter out some IP addresses of irrelevant adapters

```
for /F "delims=: tokens=2" %%G IN ('ipconfig^|find "IPv4"^|find /v " 169."') DO (set IP=%%G)
echo %IP%
pause
```

Alternatively, you can try parsing the output of netstat in a similar way